Display custom checkout field value in WooCommerce orders and email notifications with 100% discount coupon
I have the following code which adds a custom field to checkout for a specific product, adds it to the new order page, send's it in the new order email and shows on the thank you for your order page.
// Utility function: Delivery partner options (array)
function get_delivery_partner_options() {
    return array(
        ''  => __('---Please select your Delivery Partner', 'woocommerce'),
        '1' => __('Learners University College (LUC), Dubai', 'woocommerce' ),
        '2' => __('Elite Training Services (ECS), KSA ', 'woocommerce' ),
        '3' => __('MELI, KSA', 'woocommerce' ),
        '4' => __('KLD Management Training, Dubai', 'woocommerce' ),
    );
}

// Display "Delivery Partner" custom checkout field 
add_action( 'woocommerce_after_checkout_billing_form', 'my_custom_checkout_field', 10, 1 );
function my_custom_checkout_field( $checkout ) {
    
    $targeted_product_id = 6245; //Global Membership ID

    foreach( WC()->cart->get_cart() as $item ){
        if ( ! in_array($targeted_product_id, [$item['product_id'], $item['variation_id']]) ) {
            return; // Exit if there are other products in cart than the targeted one.
        }
    }

    echo '<div id="my_custom_checkout_field">
    <h2>' . __('Please select your Delivery Partner', 'woocommerce') . '</h2>';

    woocommerce_form_field( 'delivery_partner', array(
        'type'       => 'select',
        'required'   => 'true',
        'options'    => get_delivery_partner_options(),
        'class'      => array('my-field-class form-row-wide'),
        'label'      => __('Delivery Partner', 'woocommerce'),
    ), $checkout->get_value( 'delivery_partner' ));

    echo '</div>';
}

// Validate delivery partner field
add_action( 'woocommerce_checkout_process', 'custom_checkout_field_validation' );
function custom_checkout_field_validation() {
    $field_key = 'delivery_partner';
    if ( isset($_POST[$field_key]) && empty($_POST[$field_key]) ) {
        wc_add_notice( __('<strong>'.__('Delivery Partner', 'woocommerce').'</strong> is a required field.', 'woocommerce'),'error' );
    }
}

// Save the selected delivery partner as order custom metadata:
add_action( 'woocommerce_checkout_create_order', 'save_selected_delivery_partner' );
function save_selected_delivery_partner( $order ) {
    $field_key = 'delivery_partner';
    $options   = get_delivery_partner_options();
    if ( isset($_POST[$field_key]) && ! empty($_POST[$field_key]) ) {
        $order->update_meta_data( 'delivery_partner', esc_attr($options[$field_key]) );
    } 
}

// Display the custom field value on admin order pages after billing adress:
add_action( 'woocommerce_admin_order_data_after_billing_address', 'display_selected_delivery_partner_in_admin_orders', 10, 1 );
function display_selected_delivery_partner_in_admin_orders( $order ) {
    if ( $delivery_partner = $order->get_meta('delivery_partner') ) {
        echo '<p><strong>'.__('Delivery Partner', 'woocommerce').':</strong> ' . $delivery_partner . '</p>'; 
    }
}

// Display on customer orders and email notifications
add_filter( 'woocommerce_get_order_item_totals', 'display_delivery_on_order_item_totals', 10, 3 );
function display_delivery_on_order_item_totals( $total_rows, $order, $tax_display ) {
    if ( $delivery_partner = $order->get_meta('delivery_partner') ) {
        $new_total_rows = [];

        // Loop through order total rows
        foreach( $total_rows as $key => $values ) {
            // Inserting before payment method
            if( $key === 'payment_method' ) {
                $new_total_rows['gift_order'] = array(
                    'label' =>__('Delivery Partner', 'woocommerce') . ':',
                    'value' => $delivery_partner,
                );
            }
            $new_total_rows[$key] = $values;
        }
        return $new_total_rows;
    }
    return $total_rows;
}

Everything seems to be working fine apart from:  if I use a 100% discounted coupon (so the price is £0) it doesn't show up on the thank you for your order screen / email.
You will see in these images that Delivery partner is not showing when a 100% discount coupon is applied versus when its payment/cash on delivery.



You say " if I use a 100% discounted coupon it doesn't show up on the thank you…": what doesn't show up? The coupon code or the discount itself or the field value? Are you using some other related plugins that could make trouble? Try to be more explicit, updating your question.

Regarding multiple ID's its not working currently and is not showing up in the checkout against any product. Ill add an image of what im seeing when entering the coupon - im currently in a test environment with no other plugins interfering.

I have updated again my answer code here to handle multiple product IDs (tested and works).

For the coupon issue, update your question as it's unclear actually, try to better describe what happen (add some screenshots). Maybe this is related to some other code you added...

That works thank you.  I've updated my question with screen shots.  You'll see that my checkout fiels "Delivery Partners" is working when paid for / cash on delivery but is NOT when coupon is added. - With this new updated code its not working even when paid for.
